# Is disposing SXSSFWorkbook necessary when used in try with resource

Tags: apache-poi, autocloseable

Below is the sample code snippet to create `SXSSFWorkbook`:

```
try(SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook()) {
    //...
} finally {
    wb.dispose(); //wb not accessible over here, so can't use try with resource
}
```

Here problem is that if I use try with resource then can't `dispose()` `SXSSFWorkbook` in finally, as variable `wb` won't be accessible in finally block.

I wanted know that is disposing of workbook necessary to delete temporary files or since `SXSSFWorkbook` is `AutoCloseable`, try with resource will take care of it.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure whether someone of the `apache poi` programmers will answering this. But `apache poi` is open source. So every programmer can answering this itself by looking at the code.

**State May 2018, `apache poi`version `3.17`.**

[SXSSFWorkbook.java](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_3_17_BETA1/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFWorkbook.java?view=markup):

`public class SXSSFWorkbook implements Workbook`

So why can this be a resource for using in try with resource? Because

[Workbook.java](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_3_17_BETA1/src/java/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.java?view=markup):

`public interface Workbook extends Closeable, Iterable<Sheet>`

So `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook` extends `java.io.Closeable` and so classes which implements this must providing a method  `close`.

[SXSSFWorkbook.close](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_3_17_BETA1/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFWorkbook.java?view=markup#l899)

As you see, the single `SheetDataWriter`s will be closed and then the internally `XSSFWorkbook _wb` will be closed.

[SheetDataWriter.close](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_3_17_BETA1/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SheetDataWriter.java?view=markup#l121)

`SheetDataWriter.close` only flushes and closes the `Writer _out`.

So no, nowhere the `dispose` is called while auto closing until now (May 2018) in `apache poi`version `3.17`

And only [SheetDataWriter.dispose](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_3_17_BETA1/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SheetDataWriter.java?view=markup#l424) will deleting the `TempFile _fd` created for each sheet.

Answer (score 3):

This is a forrmal resolution of the problem.

```
SXSSFWorkbook t_wb = null;
try(SXSSFWorkbook wb = t_wb = new SXSSFWorkbook()) {
    //...
} finally {
    if(t_wb != null) t_wb.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Apache's example doesn't bother calling close on the workbook. Which leaves me wondering is it really needed or is the example just lacking. I loath such errant examples as the bad pattern gets replicated over and over by people naively thinking it's good.

Answer (score 1):

This question bothers me too, so my solution is to override the close method, like this:

```
//a utility method somewhere
Workbook createMyCustomWorkbook() {
    return new SXSSFWorkbook() {
        public void close() throws IOException {
            try {
                dispose();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //some logging
            }
            super.close();
        }
    };
}


//use in a simple try catch block
try(Workbook wb = createMyCustomWorkbook())
    //do stuff with wb
}
```